# How to apply the Chinese remainder theorem to $x^{3}+2x+1 \equiv 0 \bmod 15$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I want to apply the Chinese remainder theorem to the polynomial equation $ x^{3}+2x+1 \equiv 0 \bmod 15 $ which I have split into two equations $x^{3}+2x+1 \equiv 0 \bmod 3 $ and $x^{3}+2x+1 \equiv 0 \bmod 5$.

Looking at the Chinese remainder theorem the congruence equations are linear but I have seen examples which have applied the theorem to quadratic equations so  is it possible to apply it this equation?

Comment: The polynom is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3$ and $\mathbb{F}_5$.

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly fine to apply the theorem in this situation, any equation mod $15$ is equivalent to the same equation holding simultaneously mod $3$ and mod $5$.

Hint to continue: use Little Fermat's theorem.

Comment: using Fermat's little theorem : $x^{3} \equiv x mod 3$, then I would have $3x+1 \equiv 0 mod 3 $ but how would I use it for the other equation?

Comment: Umm... but there is no solution to $x^3 + 2x + 1= 0 \mod 3$.

Comment: @fleablood which step did I go wrong?

Comment: @chloeloughan You are perfectly right, but then since $3x\equiv 0\bmod 3$, you get $1\equiv 0\ldots$

Comment: @chloeloughan You didn't do *anything* wrong, there are simply no solutions to the mod 3 equation, and therefore no solutions to the initial equation.

Comment: What do you mean where do you go wrong.  You haven't solved it.  You haven't gone wrong anywhere.

Comment: I miss the day downvoters will have to explain their point of view.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier say there was a solution to the mod 3 equation. How would you use fermat or any other method to simplify the mod 5 equation to linear form?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier definitely find your answer useful. Thanks!

Comment: @chloeloughan At this point, Fermat would only help you reduce the degree of the equation, since $x^3=x^{-1}\bmod 5$ whenever $x\neq 0\bmod 5$, which gives $x^{-1}+2x+1$ and then $1+2x^2+x$ after you multiply by $x$. But checking each of the $5$ possible roots works fine as well and is faster here.

Comment: Well, one possible reason for a downvote is this implies there are solutions.  There are not.  Maybe a word to effect that we can use $x^3 +2x + 1\equiv 0 $ has no solution mod 3 or 5 then there will be no solution mod 15.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for the explanation. I guess it makes sense. My feeling was that this conclusion would be immediate after applying FLT.

Comment: I'm only guessing.  I didn't downvote and I don't think you deserved any downvotes.  And you helped the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may use the chinese remainder theorem.

$x^3+ 2x + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 3$

By Fermat $x^3 \equiv x \mod 3$ and we get the impossible $x^3 + 2x + 1 \equiv x + 2x + 1 \equiv 3x + 1 \equiv 1 \equiv 0\mod 3$. (Or we could have tried them each individually-- there's only three of them.)

so the chinese remainder theorem shows there is no solution.

====

As an example where it would have worked.  Let's let $x\equiv 6 \mod 15$ and so $x^3 + 2x + 1\equiv 4\mod 15$ so suppose we we asked to solve $x^3 + 2x -3 \equiv 0 \mod 15$.

Then $x^3 + 2x -3 \equiv 0 \mod 3$ yields

$x^3 - x \equiv 0 \mod 3$

$x(x+1)(x-1) \equiv 0 \mod 3$ and any value mod 3 will solve this.

$x^3 + 2x -3 \equiv 0 \mod 5$ yields

$x^3 + 2x +2 \equiv 0 \mod 5$.  $x = 0$ is not a solution.  So if there is any solution it is relatively prime to $5$.

$x^4 + 2x^2 + 2x \equiv 2x^2 + 2x + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 5$.

$x \equiv \frac {-2 \pm \sqrt {4 - 4*2}}{4} = 2\pm \sqrt {-1+2}\equiv 2 \pm 1$.

So $x \equiv 1,3 \mod 5$.

So solutions are all $1,3,6,8,11,13\mod 15$.  All in all, there was probably an easier way... but that was valid